# How to remove rows that have repeated elements?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe that looks like this (but for every US county)

| county | state | neighbor_county | neighbor_state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Baldwin County | AL | Clarke County | NA |
| Baldwin County | AL | Escambia County | FL |
| Baldwin County | AL | Mobile County | NA |
| Baldwin County | AL | Monroe County | NA |
| Barbour County | AL | Dale County | NA |
| Barbour County | AL | Henry County | NA |

I am only interested in what states neighbor a county, so I want to remove repeated data to get this (step 1):

| county | state | neighbor_state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Baldwin County | AL | NA |
| Baldwin County | AL | FL |
| Barbour County | AL | NA |

And then change sort the dataframe like this (step 2):

| county | state | neighbor_state_1 | neighbor_state_2 | neighbor_state_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Baldwin County | AL | FL | NA | NA |
| Baldwin County | AL | NA | NA | NA |

In step 1 I've deleted the "neighbor_county" column; however, I've not managed to remove the duplicates in the column "neighbor_state" for each distinct county. I have tried using the unique function but I can't seem to make it work such that it only removes duplicates of each distinct county.

Comment: What is your rule for step 2?

Comment: Is `NA` the `NA`-value or a state?

Comment: NA is the NA-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first step you could drop the `neighbour_county` column and the use `unique()`:

```r
df$neighbor_county <- NULL
unique(df)
```

returns

```r
          county state neighbor_state
1 Baldwin_County    AL             NA
2 Baldwin_County    AL             FL
5 Barbour_County    AL             NA
```

An alternative using `dplyr`:

```r
df %>% 
  select(-neighbor_county) %>% 
  distinct()
```

For your second step I make a suggestion:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(county) %>% 
  select(-neighbor_county) %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=n, names_prefix="neighbor_state_", values_from=neighbor_state) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  county         state neighbor_state_1 neighbor_state_2 neighbor_state_3 neighbor_state_4
  <chr>          <chr> <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
1 Baldwin_County AL    'NA'             'FL'             'NA'             'NA'            
2 Barbour_County AL    'NA'             'NA'             NA               NA
```

but I'm not sure, if this is what you are looking for.

For removing doubled `NA`-values, you could use

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(county) %>% 
  select(-neighbor_county) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=n, names_prefix="neighbor_state_", values_from=neighbor_state) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

### Data

```r
structure(list(county = c("Baldwin_County", "Baldwin_County", 
"Baldwin_County", "Baldwin_County", "Barbour_County", "Barbour_County"
), state = c("AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL"), neighbor_county = c("Clarke_County", 
"Escambia_County", "Mobile_County", "Monroe_County", "Dale_County", 
"Henry_County"), neighbor_state = c("'NA'", "'FL'", "'NA'", "'NA'", 
"'NA'", "'NA'")), problems = structure(list(row = 6L, col = "neighbor_state", 
    expected = "", actual = "embedded null", file = "literal data"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(county = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), state = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), neighbor_county = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), neighbor_state = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Step 1 worked as intended. Step 2 also works to an extent– it gives me the desired table; however, I end up with  48 "neighbor_state" columns where in each row most entries are NA. Ideally I would compress that to the minimum number "neighbor_state" columns possible. I think I understand the problem and will also seek for a solution

Comment: If you get 48 neighbor_state columns there is at least one row containing 48 entries. You can't compress them unless you remove all doubled entries in your columns.

Comment: Yes, I now have to remove the duplicate NA values in  "neighbor_state_1" ...  "neighbor_state_48" for each row. I will try to do that!

Comment: Added a line to remove doubled `NA`-values.