# Moving elements from column to column in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this (but for every US county)

| county | state | n_state_1 | n_state_2 | n_state_3 | n_state_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Autauga County | AL | NA | FL | NA | NA |
| Baldwin County | AL | GA | NA | TN | NA |
| Catron County | AL | FL | GA | NA | CA |

I want to move the non-missing values (FL,GA,TN etc.) to the first columns starting from n_state_1 and then delete the columns containing only missing values to get:

| county | state | n_state_1 | n_state_2 | n_state_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Autauga County | AL | FL | NA | NA |
| Baldwin County | AL | GA | TN | NA |
| Catron County | AL | FL | GA | CA |

I am struggling with the first step. I thought about using the function distinct but it doesn't work because there are non-empty elements in each column.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68245914/how-to-remove-rows-that-have-repeated-elements/68246062#68246062

Comment: [Shifting non-NA cells to the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285215/shifting-non-na-cells-to-the-left) and Linked therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("n_state")) %>% 
  drop_na() %>%
  group_by(county, state) %>% 
  mutate(name=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_prefix="n_state_")
```

which returns

```r
  county         state n_state_1 n_state_2 n_state_3
  <chr>          <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1 Autauga_County AL    FL        NA        NA       
2 Baldwin_County AL    GA        TN        NA       
3 Catron_County  AL    FL        GA        CA
```

**What happened here?**

- `pivot_longer` takes the `n_state_{n}`-columns and collapses them into two columns: the `name`-column contains the original column name (`n_state_1`, `n_state_2` etc), the `value`-column contains the states (`FL`, `GA` or `<NA>` in many cases).
- Next we remove every `<NA>` entry. (Note: I use `<NA>` to make clear it's an `NA`-value).)
- After a grouping by `county` and `state` we add a rownumber. These numbers will be later used to create the new column names.
- `pivot_wider` now takes these row numbers and prefixes them with `n_state_` to get the new columns. The values are taken from the `value`-column created in the second line of code. `pivot_wider` fills the missing values with `<NA>`-values (default behaviour).

### Data

```r
structure(list(county = c("Autauga_County", "Baldwin_County", 
"Catron_County"), state = c("AL", "AL", "AL"), n_state_1 = c(NA, 
"GA", "FL"), n_state_2 = c("FL", NA, "GA"), n_state_3 = c(NA, 
"TN", NA), n_state_4 = c(NA, NA, "CA")), problems = structure(list(
    row = 3L, col = "n_state_4", expected = "", actual = "embedded null", 
    file = "literal data"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(county = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), state = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), n_state_1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), n_state_2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), n_state_3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), n_state_4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: It worked exactly how I wanted it:) but I don't quite follow the code even after looking into it. In particular, I don't understand what is going on in the second line (the pivot_longer function) and the last line. If you could provide some intuition, I'd be extremely grateful!

Comment: Added a brief explanation to clearify the code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Or another option with `dapply` from `collapse` and `select` only columns with `any` non-NA elements

```
library(collapse)
library(dplyr)
dapply(df1, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])) %>%
   select(where(~ any(complete.cases(.))))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  county         state n_state_1 n_state_2 n_state_3
  <chr>          <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1 Autauga_County AL    FL        <NA>      <NA>     
2 Baldwin_County AL    GA        TN        <NA>     
3 Catron_County  AL    FL        GA        CA
```